# How exactly do outputs work?

Tags: transaction-data

Suppose someone gives me 1 XMR, that I'll call 'A'. That person can now see when that output A they give me is used in a ring signature for a transaction. If I then make a transaction where I send 0.1 XMR, I send that 1 XMR output A and then receive 0.9 in change right? Now how does the tracking of A work now? If I go and make another transaction using the 0.9 in my wallet, will that initial output A once again be used in that transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Oversimplified:

```
1.0 (alice)
└── 1.0 (YOU - output A)
    ├── 0.1 (bob)
    └── 0.9 (YOU - output B)
        └── 0.9 (charlie)
```

By the time you send to charlie, there are no more funds left in A, so it cannot serve as actual output any more.